# Apache can't start after installing with windows server 2008 r2

Tags: apache

[apache can't start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Tgwo.png)

I don't know what to do. Can somebody help me? 
Thank you!

Comment: Most likely IIS already running on that port.

Comment: How can I know it? Thank you

Comment: and how do I erase IIS on the port? Thank you